# Google Open Authentication From Localhost

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-identity, google-openid

Im New to open authentication and i want to use this angularjs plugin (satelizer) that handles open authentication
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer
and then use it to register user to asp.net identity my first problem is 
when i set my google token to this plugin i face error 400 - redirect_uri_mismatch i realised that its about authenticating from localhost but i already added http://localhost:2274 to my google web developer console but same error occured what should i do? then my second problem is after first problem solved and user authenticated in google how could i send user authentication information and set it to asp.net identity **Note that i know its a duplicate Question but these answers didn't solved mine**